# Alert dialog setNeutralButton not showing on Nexus 5

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, nexus-5

I am facing this weird issue.

I have an alert dialog with setPossitiveButton, but it doesn't shows on Nexus 5, only the message part shows up. I tried with neutral button also.

I verified this on another device of my friend (not nexus 5), and its working there too.

Is there something wrong with it ?

Below is the code:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
               .setMessage(R.string.no_result)
               .setCancelable(true)
               .setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                       dialog.dismiss();
                       finish();
                   }})
               .setNeutralButton(R.string.search_again, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                   }})
               .show();
```

Comment: have you check your style.xml? may be there is issue with dialogue theme.

Comment: @KDeogharkar I am not able to understand how that will interfere with this. Any example ?

Comment: are you using support `AlertDialog` or `app.AlertDialog` ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna : android.app.AlertDialog

Comment: do you mean `search_again` is not showing ? it  is showing in my nexus 5. with same code.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna : Yes its not showing. Try this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=instore.rapido

Comment: @ShreeKrishna : Enter some long random text, so that you don't find any search result, you will see a pop up then.

Comment: It's my emulator actually. But as you told it's working fine in other devices. And as your situation Message is showing but button is not showing is it ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna : Yes, its happening on my client device, which is Nexus 5, on one of  my friend Nexus 4, its fine.

Comment: It's a really complex issue, But what I want to suggest is first try `AlertDialog` from support library, second setPositiveButton before others and 3rd is Just create an instance of `AlertDialog.Builder` and create it again before showing like here...
 `AlertDialog dialog1 = dialog.create();` 
 `dialog1.show();` 
I know it's same and won't make vast different but, Try once. Miner things may be solved with miner changes.

Comment: ok I will try support library also

Comment: Updating after a long time, but it worked with support library. Looks like old package is broken now.